# Display dynamic data to footer only using Laravel traits

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a trait in my Laravel project it have a class named "A". It returns some values. In my controller I call the trait and inside the controller I call the trai using "use traitname".next I call those function in index() with `$this->A();`. It only includes on `index()` not for all.I have lots of function in my controller.And now my problem is I need to edit with `$this->A()` to get data in footer when all pages runs.Is there any changes to define the traits once in my specified controller and use that trait return value in footerpage for a specified user using Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using View Composers instead of traits for this purpose. View Composers are a way to share common logic between views, which would be a good fit for displaying dynamic data in the footer.

Another way, which may be an even better fit depending on your use case, is to have all your blade page views extend a common layout, and put the logic in the footer in the layout file.